# I AM NOT ABLE TO PLAY A GIF IN TKINTER

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

I have been trying to put a  GIF  in tkinter.

**[GIF THAT I NEED HELP WITH]:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/64SG8.gif

But for some reason, it is not coming properly and some pixel at a time only. Could someone help me with it?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

root=Tk()
file="preview.gif"

info = Image.open(file)

frames = info.n_frames  # gives total number of frames that gif contains

# creating list of PhotoImage objects for each frames
im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

count = 0
anim = None
def animation(count):
    global anim
    im2 = im[count]

    gif_label.configure(image=im2)
    count += 1
    if count == frames:
        count = 0
    anim = root.after(50,lambda :animation(count))

def stop_animation():
    root.after_cancel(anim)

gif_label = tk.Label(root,image="")
gif_label.pack()

start = tk.Button(root,text="start",command=lambda :animation(count))
start.pack()

stop = tk.Button(root,text="stop",command=stop_animation)
stop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try to run this program it hangs on the list comprehension creating the frame list `im`.

Pillow has a neat function for getting frames of an animated gif. Example below, using slightly different object names but nonetheless:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence

...

file = "preview.gif"
animated_gif = Image.open(file)

image_frame_list = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(animated_gif):
    image_frame_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=frame))
im = image_frame_list
```